# How to get the load time of a web page using chrome console window and console commands?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How can I get the load time of a web page in Chrome's JavaScript console?

I openede google.com and tried the following commands: `console.time`, `console.loadTime`. Is there a specific command which I can use to obtain the full load time of a given page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the deprecated [`window.performance.timing`](https://w3c.github.io/navigation-timing/#obsolete) API to see different events and their timestamps. To calculate the load time for a page in milliseconds, get the time difference between the `loadEventEnd` and `navigationStart` like this:

```js
window.performance.timing.loadEventEnd - window.performance.timing.navigationStart
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Performance tab in the developer tools and click on the refresh icon in the performance tab.